# Is there a way to prevent billing in Windows Azure trial offers?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

There is a new trial offer available for windows Azure which gives you 25 hours of small computing instance time a month and other things like 1 GB SQL Azure and more. See link below: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/popup/popup.aspx?lang=en&locale=en-US&offer=MS-AZR-0001P

Now my question: Is there a way to prevent exceeding these limits? I only want to try and don't want to be billed.

Comment: Outlook calendar reminders work pretty well. Are you looking for a programmatic solution of some kind?

Comment: I'd definitely recommend you use the extra small instance time rather than the small instance - at least 750 hours will last you a month

Comment: Also, be very aware that instances are charged in whole hour units - so if you upload an image to an instance for a minute and then delete it, then that's 1 hour gone - even if you never Run that instance. Similarly if you upload a package which specifies 10 role instances, then you are charging starts immediately for 10 instance hours.

Comment: As an additional answer, I've just seen on  "Getting started: If you’re looking to try out the Windows Azure Platform free for 30-days—without using a credit card—try the Windows Azure Pass with promo code “CloudCover”.  For more details, see Try Out Windows Azure with a Free Pass." - http://watoolkitwp7.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know there is no automated way to have it turn it off before you get billed. You will need to just be very careful about monitoring your usage manually.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you don't need a credit card to use the 30 day pass - the one from here:

http://windowsazurepass.com/

Answer (score 0):

For Doobi's suggestion, I believe you need a promo code to get the free 30 day trial.  There is a MSDN blog post with the [code MPR001 here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ignitionshowcase/archive/2011/01/11/the-windows-azure-platform-30-day-pass-free-trial-no-credit-card-required.aspx).